# I need query to get count of data with respect to XML

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Campaign`  with a column `CampaignXml` plus other columns. In `CampaignXml`, I save questions. I need a query to get the number of questions from all `CampaignXml` columns.

I wrote a stored procedure using `top 1 CampaignXML` from `Campaign` table, but I want to look at all `CampaignXml` in the table and get the question counts.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPanelsitCount]
AS
    DECLARE @CampaignXML NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @idoc INT    

    DECLARE @Marketid INT

    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 @CampaignXML = CampaignXML, @marketid = marketid          
    FROM dbo.Campaign          
    WHERE campaigntypeid = 8 
      AND CampaignXML IS NOT NULL  
      AND statusid = 57    
      AND marketid = 24

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT          

  ,@CampaignXML   

   (SELECT ID  INTO #tblQuestionId FROM OPENXML(@idoc, 'XmlCampiagn/Pages/Page[1]/Questions/Question') WITH (ID INT '@ID'))    
    -- select * from    #tblQuestionId
```

Sample XML:

```
<XmlCampiagn Name='My Campaign' ID='4'>
    <GlobalSetting Name='Global Setting'>
        <MobileNumberVerification Enabled='False' Mandatory='False' Required='False'></MobileNumberVerification>
        <XGEOTargeting Enabled='False'></XGEOTargeting>
        <Captcha Enabled='False'></Captcha>
    </GlobalSetting>
    <Pages>
        <Page ID= '1' Name='Default' PageType='Default' Mode='0'>
            <PipingLogics></PipingLogics>
            <Questions>
                 <Question MaxLength='' Validation='' ID='6448' 
                           Mandatory='True' Required='False' IsNonEditable='False'/>
            </Questions>
            <Logics></Logics>
            <Masking‌​Logics></MaskingLogi‌​cs>
        </Page>
    </Pages>
</‌​XmlCampiagn>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with the **native XQuery** support in SQL Server - no need to use `sp_xml_preparedocument` or anything legacy stuff like that....

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CampaignId, 
    CAST(CampaignXml AS XML).value('count(//Question)', 'int')
FROM
    dbo.Campaign
WHERE 
    CampaignTypeId = 8 
    AND CampaignXml IS NOT NULL  
    AND StatusId = 57    
    AND MarketId = 24
```

This will give you the `CampaignId` and the count of questions (all questions on all of the possibly multiple `<Page>` subelements) for that campaign. If you need *only* the total overall, use this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CAST(CampaignXml AS XML).value('count(//Question)', 'int'))
FROM
    dbo.Campaign
WHERE 
    CampaignTypeId = 8 
    AND CampaignXml IS NOT NULL  
    AND StatusId = 57    
    AND MarketId = 24
```

Comment: thanks but i am getting  error..Cannot find either column "CampaignXML" or the user-defined function or aggregate "CampaignXML.value", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: @M.Hasan: well, what **datatype** is your `CampaignXml` column? Since you said it stores XML, I assume it's of `XML` datatype - if not, then the `.value()` is not possible, of course.....

Comment: its nvarchar datatype

Comment: but we storing XML data in this column

Comment: like this..<XmlCampiagn Name='My Campaign' ID='4'><GlobalSetting Name='Global Setting'><MobileNumberVerification Enabled='False' Mandatory='False' Required='False'> </MobileNumberVerification><XGEOTargeting Enabled='False'> </XGEOTargeting><Captcha Enabled='False'> </Captcha></GlobalSetting><Pages><Page ID= '1' Name='Default' PageType='Default' Mode='0'><PipingLogics></PipingLogics><Questions><Question MaxLength='' Validation='' ID='6448' Mandatory='True' Required='False' IsNonEditable='False'/></Questions><Logics></Logics><MaskingLogics></MaskingLogics></Page></Pages></XmlCampiagn>

Comment: @M.Hasan: if it's XML - make the datatype `XML` ! It's more efficient than `Nvarchar`, and it allows you to use XQuery functions on it. Also: your root element is spelled wrong - it should be `<XmlCampaign>` - not `<XmlCampiagn>` ....

Comment: @M.Hasan: updated my response to handle `nvarchar` data - but again: **CHANGE** your column datatype to **`XML`** !

Comment: sorry i can't change because its existing table.I can't modify it.It refers to many place and in many sps